# javascript - Stack issue?

Tags: javascript, data-structures, stack

when i console log the stack class i want to see the Stack with removed elements ,but the program just tells removed but stack still same,

**output**
﻿

100 added to 0

200 added to 1

500 added to 2

400 added to 3

800 added to 4

800 removed

Stack {item: Array(5), count: 4} **i want array length to be 4**

count: 4
item: Array(5)

0: 100
1: 200
2: 500
3: 400
4: 800
length: 5

```js
class Stack {
  constructor() {
    this.item = [];
    this.count = 0;
  }

  // Add Elements to stack

  push(element) {
    this.item[this.count] = element;
    console.log(`${element} added to ${this.count}`);
    this.count += 1;
    return this.count - 1;
  }

  pop() {
    if (this.count === 0) return undefined;
    let deleteItem = this.item[this.count - 1];
    console.log(this.count);
    this.count -= 1;
    console.log(`${deleteItem} removed`);
    return deleteItem;
  }
}

let stack = new Stack();

stack.push(100);
stack.push(200);
stack.push(500);
stack.push(400);
stack.push(800);

stack.pop();

console.log(stack);
```

Comment: in `Stack#pop` you are not removing the item from `this.item` or changing that array at all. What do you want to do here? Are you trying to avoid using array methods?

Comment: i am new to this and right now i am trying to learn so here i want remove the element from stack , right now i dont understand  what should i put after assignment operator this.item[this.count - 1] =  ;  ?

Answer (score 0):

In the `pop` method of the `Stack` class, it is necessary to remove the last element from `this.item`. Note that JavaScript arrays already have `.push()` and `.pop()` methods, so they can behave as stacks natively.

```js
class Stack {
  constructor() {
    this.item = [];
    this.count = 0;
  }

  // Add Elements to stack

  push(element) {
    this.item[this.count] = element;
    console.log(`${element} added to ${this.count}`);
    this.count += 1;
    return this.count - 1;
  }

  pop() {
    if (this.count === 0) return undefined;
    let deleteItem = this.item.pop();
    console.log(this.count);
    this.count -= 1;
    console.log(`${deleteItem} removed`);
    return deleteItem;
  }
}

let stack = new Stack();

stack.push(100);
stack.push(200);
stack.push(500);
stack.push(400);
stack.push(800);

stack.pop();

console.log(stack);
```

Comment: how i approach to remove the last element from this stack any suggestion ?

Comment: @Mrunknown `this.item.pop()` will remove the last element. Do you want to do it without calling the `pop()` method?

Comment: no i want to use the method to remove element

Comment: The method does remove the element, doesn't it? if you want to have a more _fancy_ method use something like this `let deleteItem = stack.splice(stack.length -1, 1)`

Comment: **Error** Uncaught TypeError: stack.splice is not a function

Comment: Yes that's why I wrote something like this. You have to use your correct variables and this and so on. But in the end it does not matter sbgibs answer is perfectly valid and the way to go.